# How to set parentheses matching colors

Tags: highlighting, parentheses

When using parentheses matching, how can I set the color of the parenthesis my cursor is actually on?

I found I can use the below `set-face-attribute` to control the color of the *other* parenthesis, but I cannot find any info on how to control the color of the parenthesis I am on.

```
(set-face-attribute 'show-paren-match nil
                    :background "#ffffff"
                    :foreground "#000000")
```

Comment: Are you looking for [rainbow-delimiters](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters) by any chance? The package is available in MELPA as well.

Comment: In addition to `rainbow-delimiters` you may find [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) of interest.

Comment: @NickD: I guess OP only wants to change `show-paren-mode`’s color...

Comment: Search this site for `[parentheses] [highlight]`.

Answer (score 3):

`C-h f show-paren-mode`:

> `show-paren-mode` is an interactive native-compiled Lisp function in
> ‘[paren.el](https://1.1.1.1)’.

Click ‘[paren.el](https://1.1.1.1)’ in your Emacs.

Find the definition of the function `show-paren-function`, and see:

```lisp
(overlay-put show-paren--overlay-1 'face face))
;; ...
;; ...
(overlay-put show-paren--overlay 'face face))))))
```

You can replace the `face` (not `'face`) with `'(:background "yellow" :foreground "red")`, then reevaluate this `defun` form.

---

The above steps will change how `show-paren-mode` displays color.

You may want to add some code to your `.emacs` to automate the above process.

Comment: Sincerely, `rainbow-delimiters` or `highlight-parentheses` may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs comes with the convenient possibility to adjust all of the own settings using the therefore provided buffer interfaces.

To access properties of font faces choose in Emacs menu:

```
MENU: 
     Options: 
              Customize Emacs:
                               Specific Face ...
```

The buffer opened by this menu item comes with a `[Search]` function helping to find the appropriate face settings.

The keywords to use to get the settings related to highlighting parentheses are: **'paren'** and **'face'** (I must admit not that easy to guess ...):

[image: dialog buffer]

The color of the matching parenthesis can be set from there by opening the `Show Paren Match` dialog (click the left triangle) and the color of the parenthesis you are at (assuming that there is no match) by opening the `Show Paren Mismatch`:

[image]

With the settings above you will get:

[image: closing paren]   [image: orphan paren]

To my knowledge *it is not possible* to set the color of the parenthesis you are at to a different color as the color of the matching parenthesis. And even if it would be possible, it would not make much sense anyway.

Comment: After I choose `Options> Customize Emacs> Specific Face` the mini-buffer at the bottom of the frame says, `Customize face (default all faces):`  If I hit return to accept the default, then the Search bar shown in the screenshot opens in a buffer.  I chose white for the color, and now I can see the parens through the white.   Before I had steel-gray, and it wasn't transparent.  To change the cursor color, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234743

Comment: To bring up the Search bar, you can also do `M-x customize-face <Ret> <Ret>`.